# How to set time space between interstetial ads across multiple uses in libGdx

Tags: libgdx, ads

i'm building a simple Ketchapp style game and i want an interstitial ad to appear when the player dies.

This is the current class i am using, the constructor is used when the game starts and the adCheck method runs when the player dies.

```
public class GameOverAd {
    private static final int RESET = -1;

    private static long startTime = RESET;
    private static long currentTime;
    private static int secondsPassedSinceLastAd;

    public GameOverAd(){
        if (startTime == RESET){
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //first time showOrLoadInterstitial() runs it will load the ad
            //second time showOrLoadInterstitial() runs it will show the ad
            GameMain.handler.showOrLoadInterstitial();//loads
        }
    }

    public void adCheck(){
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        secondsPassedSinceLastAd = (int)((currentTime - startTime) /1000);
        if(secondsPassedSinceLastAd >= 20){//seconds between ads
            showAd();
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    public void showAd(){
        GameMain.handler.showOrLoadInterstitial();//shows add
        startTime = RESET;
    }
}
```

This code works fine as long as the player does not close the app, it shows an add after 250 seconds of use when the player dies, but the problem is that if the player quits after 249 seconds the timer resets and the user will never see an ad. How do i make the timer keep counting from the same place it left off?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save the time left upon close and read it back when the app starts. I suggest using the Preferences class for this